# What does the "spirit" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

From VOA:

> Jewel’s first holiday album, “Joy,” came out in 1999 and has sold over a million copies. She says her new one, “Let It Snow,” has the same ***spirit*** as the first.

What does the word "spirit" mean? I cannot find a proper meaning in the dictionary. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This can be a tough one because the sentence is utilizing a metaphor.  Here, Jewel is saying that the second album has a ***spirit***.  A look at [Googl](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3aspirit&oq=define%3aspirit&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2986j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)e gives as one of the possible definitions for spirit:

> those ***qualities regarded as forming the definitive or typical elements***
>   ***in the character*** of a person, nation, or group or in the thought and
>   attitudes of a particular period

Focusing on the highlighted portion of the definition, we can interpret Jewel's comment saying that the two albums share the same qualities that define the character of the albums. In other words, she believes that the two albums share some, perhaps otherwise indescribable, core characteristics.